# Question on Clocks

Tags: arithmetic

> Three watches are set together. The first gains $5$ minutes a week, the second gains $8$ minutes a week, whilst the third loses $4$ minutes a week. When will they again indicate the same time?

Please give me some hint on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: 1 second later; the time haven't change. (Unless your clocks are very specific...)

Comment: even in 1 sec all the three clocks will gain or loose a fraction of second that's why your assumption may be wrong.

Comment: but how specific is the watch? 1 second?

Comment: I guess more than that.

Comment: Are these 12 hour watches or 24 hour watches, i.e. does AM/PM matter?

Comment: 12 hour watches, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- 12-hour watches.  So two watches that differ by $12 \times 60\ $ accumulated minutes are indicating the same time.  So not one of [these](http://www.webwatchworld.com/raketa-24-hour/).
- "The same time" means "have hands pointing at the same labels" (no a.m. vs. p.m. tracking, so not one of [these](http://www.worldofluxuryus.com/img/grey01/wt/Day-Night-AM-PM-indicator.jpg))
- Time is (miraculously) indicated with infinite precision.  (The accuracy is somewhat lacking, though.)

The first two differ by 3 minutes per week, so at least $\frac{12 \times 60}{3} = 240$ weeks must pass before the first two watches indicate the same time.  This will recur every 240 weeks.  The first and last differ by 9 minutes per week, so $\frac{12 \times 60}{9} = 80$ weeks is the time between matches of the first and last watch.  Conveniently, this divides 240 weeks, so all three watches will agree every 240 weeks.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why 12.60?

Comment: 12 hours times 60 minutes -- the number of minutes between identical readings.

Comment: Thank you Sir. It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are $720$ minutes in $12$ hours. So, the time on the watches is modulo $720$ minutes.

Thus, the clocks show the same time after $n$ weeks iff $5n \equiv 8n \equiv -4n \pmod{720}$.

This condition is met iff $3n \equiv 0 \pmod{720}$, i.e. $n$ is a multiple of $240$.

So, the watches will show the same time after $240$ weeks.

Comment: How would you explain it to a 9th grade student?

Comment: Replace "$5n \equiv 8n \equiv -4n \pmod{720}$" with "$8n-5n$ and $5n-(-4n)$ are multiples of $720$", and replace "$3n \equiv 0 \pmod{720}$" with "$3n$ is a multiple of $720$".